# cfdirectory loop limit the results

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop, cfdirectory

I' am finding it difficult to understand this. How can I limit the results to 50 only. Let say if in the directory I have 1000 files, how can I limit it so that only 50 files are looped over.

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#ExpandPath('/downloaded/')#" name="listRoot" filter="*.xml" recurse="false" sort="datelastmodified asc">
<cfoutput>
   <cfloop query="listRoot" from="1" to="50" index="i">
           ....
   </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

When I run the above code I get the following error message

> Attribute validation error for tag CFLOOP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you review the complete error message, it contains the answer (emphasis mine):

> *It has an invalid attribute combination: from,index,query,to. **Possible combinations are**:*
>
> - Required attributes: **'query'**. Optional attributes: **'endrow,startrow'**.
> - ...
> - Required attributes: **'from,index,to'**. Optional attributes: **'step'**.

The code is attempting to mix two different types of loops: query loop and from/to loop. That is not a valid combination. You can either use a `query` loop *OR* a `from/to` loop, but not both.

Having said that, since the goal is to display the output, there is really no need for the `cfloop`. Just use [cfoutput](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfoutput.html) with the "startRow" and "maxRows" attributes:

```
   <cfoutput query="listRoot" startRow="1" maxRows="50">
       #name#<br>
   </cfoutput>
```

As mentioned in the other answer, recent versions of CF also support [`for ...in` loops](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fdf.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fe8):

```
<cfscript>
   for (row in listRoot) {
      writeOutput("<br>Debug: name value = "& row.name );
   }
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access specific rows in a query with:

`query[columnName][rowIndex]`

In order to do a `from to loop` instead of an `each loop`, go:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="50" index="i">
        #listRoot["name"][i]#<br>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```